# Checking collision from below using OnCollisionEnter

Tags: unity, collision-detection

Want to use OnCollisionEnter to see if there is a collision from below.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
     {
         foreach (ContactPoint contact in other.contacts) 
         {
             if(contact.point.y<transform.position.y)
             {
                 Debug.Log("Collision from below");
             }
         }
         collision = true;
     }
```

it doesn't work for me

Comment: And what's wrong with how you're doing it now? Be specific "it doesn't work for me" is not at all clear.

Answer (score -1):

1.For that just create Empty game object with collider on it.

2.Attach it to bottom of object.

3.Done

Comment: It's clear from the question that OP needs more detailed instructions and it's not such a simple answer.

Comment: I do not get why I got negative rating.My answer is totally relevant.May be short but it does the job.If OP wants further detail I will be happy to provide.